# Reutilizing Geojson layer in Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, leaflet, folium

I am using Folium to add multiple Geojson layers over the same geographical area and demarcation. The problem is that for each layer that I add the file size increases significantly.

I looked at the resulting html file and it creates one Geojson object for each layer. Is there a way of reutilizing the geojson object? The only difference across layers is the colors that are used to paint them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're utilizing the same geojson object each time and changin the style/color based on some rule:

```
folium.GeoJson(geo_json_data,
                style_function=lambda feature: {
                'fillColor':'green' if feature['properties']['some_property']==1 else 'red', 
                'color': 'black',
                'weight': 2,
                'dashArray': '5, 5'}
                ).add_to(map)
```

Should work. Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue